# xml and repeaters

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

Do I have to use XPath to link my XML document 
to a repeater or is there another way.

here is my some of my code.

first page loop through data and store as XML:

```
public virtual void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
          {

             TableControl recControls = (TableControl)this.Page.FindControlRecursively("TableControl");
              if (recControls != null)
              {
                  TableControlRow[] rows = recControls.GetSelectedRecordControls();
                  this.Page.Session["RegistrationTableControl"] = rows;

                  // create XML writer to 
                  using(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer = System.Xml.XmlWriter.Create(@"c:\temp\reg.xml"))
                  {
                      XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
                      settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
                      settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;
                      settings.CloseOutput = false;



                      writer.WriteStartDocument();
                      writer.WriteStartElement("SubContractors");
                      foreach(TableControlRow rec in rows)
                      {

                          writer.WriteElementString("SubContrator1", rec.BUSINESSNAME.Text);
                          writer.WriteElementString("SubContactName1", rec.OWNERNAME.Text);
                          writer.WriteElementString("SubAddress1", rec.ADDRESS.Text);
                          writer.WriteElementString("SubCity1", rec.CITY.Text);
                          writer.WriteElementString("SubState1", rec.STATE.Text);
                          writer.WriteElementString("SubZipCode1", rec.ZIPCODE.Text);
                          writer.WriteElementString("SubPhone1", rec.PHONE.Text);
                          writer.WriteElementString("SubFax1", rec.FAX.Text);
                          writer.WriteElementString("SubEmail1", rec.EMAIL.Text);
                          writer.WriteElementString("Status1", "Please enter information");
                          writer.WriteElementString("Referral", "1");

                      }
                      writer.WriteEndElement();
                      writer.WriteEndDocument();
                 }


              }}
```

Which creates my xml document.

Page 2 Code: I need to take the data in the newly create XML document and 
populate my table control repeater work with this code.

on page 2

```
public override void DataBind()
    {
        base.DataBind();


        // Make sure that the DataSource is initialized.
        if (this.DataSource == null)
        {
            return;
        }
         // Setup the pagination controls.
        BindPaginationControls();

        // Populate all filters data.

        // Bind the repeater with the list of records to expand the UI.
        System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater rep = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater)(this.FindControl("TableControlRepeater"));
        rep.DataSource = this.DataSource;
        rep.DataBind();

        int index = 0;
        foreach (System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItem repItem in rep.Items)
        {

            // Make sure that the DataSource is initialized.


            // Loop through all rows in the table, set its DataSource and call DataBind().
            TableControlRow recControl = (TableControlRow)(repItem.FindControl("TableControlRow"));
            recControl.DataSource = this.DataSource[index];
            recControl.DataBind();
            recControl.Visible = !this.InDeletedRecordIds(recControl);
            index += 1;
        }
    }
```

I have take the XML data and place them in page 2 become the data source of the repeater.

Any help or suggestion is very helpful. I would really not to have to rewrite the code.

Comment: Is... there a reason you're converting everything to XML (by hand, too) and then reading it back?

Answer (score 1):

LINQ-To-XML is probably the most simple way to accomplish this task. See Scott Gu's [post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/07/using-linq-to-xml-and-how-to-build-a-custom-rss-feed-reader-with-it.aspx) on it.

pseudo-code:

```
var xml = XDocument.Load(...);
reapeater.DataSource = from x in xml.Descendents("z") 
    where x.Attributes("y").Equals("select value") 
    select new { Value1 = x.Element("Value1"), Value2 = x.Element("Value2") };
repeater.DataBind();
```

Comment: question ("z") is SubContrctors

Comment: You'll have to play around with it based on your xml output; however, based on the code you updated with, I might suggest using XML Seralization, since it will be fully automatic.

Answer (score 0):

I use [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb387098.aspx)

for querying XML documents it is much easier.